# Rails method working in console but not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have a rails app that is using Redis as the DB, and Ohm as an ORM.

I have a model `Activity` that has a set of `Users`. In the rails console I am able to call `Activity[id].users.to_a` and get the expected list. When trying to do the same thing in a method in my app, I always get an empty string. I've tried this several different ways, including using `self.users.to_a` in the method and nothing has worked.

I haven't come across a problem like this before where everything is working fine in console but not in the app. BTW the rails.env is set to development.

Any help would be really appreciated, this has stumped me for a bit now. Thanks.

**Activity.rb**

```
class Activity < Ohm::Model
  include Ohm::Timestamps
  include Ohm::DataTypes
  include Ohm::Callbacks
  include ModuleLibrary

  attribute :type
  index :type
  attachment :attached
  attribute :time, Type::Integer
  attribute :description
  attribute :to_calendar, Type::Integer
  set :contacts, :Contact
  set :users, :User
  reference :company, :Company
  reference :account, :Account

  def user_names #empty string in app, works fine in console
    users.map(&:name).to_sentence
  end
end
```

EDIT: So apparently it turns out where I was calling the method from, the users hadn't been added yet. (duh!) I moved where the method is called to a different spot, and it's all working now.

Comment: Does `Activity[id].user_names` work in the console?

Comment: If your question is answered please add your own answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Please write the solution as an answer and accept it.